# layer-list drawable rendered incorrectly in Api 21

Tags: android, xml, drawable, layer-list

I have a LayerList Drawable with a rectangular shape. I'm facing an issue where the Drawable is shown differently in Api 28 vs Api 21. Here is my code.

LayerListDrawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is how its rendered in Api 21:-

[image]

This is how it's rendered in Api 28:-

[image]

Comment: read `LayerDrawable` API documentation - in particular when `android:width` was introduced

Comment: @pskink the `android:width` and `android:height` were introduced in api 23.. but i'm using `size` tag with which i'm getting expected result in Api 28. Could you please tell what i seem to be missing? Is `size` property or `gravity` not backward compatible?

Comment: you use `<size android:width="2dp" />` right? it is not supported before API 23 - see `LayerDrawable#setLayerWidth` method (and when it was added)

Comment: Thank you, i got confused by ShapeDrawable's width and height attribute.. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html#attr_android:width. Is there an alternate way to set width of drawable? i tried `ScaleDrawable`, `nine_patch`, `<bitmap>` with `tileModeX=disabled`. None has worked so far.

Comment: i dont know what actually do you want to achieve....

Comment: i want to write a `LayerDrawable` that looks like the second image on both lollipop and pie

Comment: why `LayerDrawable`? do you want to have multiple layers or what?

Comment: Yes, actually in my app i have four layers.. each layer is a border to the `ImageView`. I have individual layers for each border because i need to modify their opacity at runtime. Each layer has the `ShapeDrawable` code in my question with appropriate gravity.

Comment: Thank you, i will try extending Shape and override onDraw and update how it goes here

Comment: @pskink Hi pskink, Here is the update. i have worked around this problem by drawing borders in a custom `ImageView`. I removed borders from my `LayerDrawable` and setting it to custom `ImageView` to display other shapes. Its working so far. Thank you for helping me with this.